# Why are atexit handlers not executed with subprocess, but os.system?

Tags: python, subprocess

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system states that `os.system()` can be replaced with `subprocess.call(…, shell=True)`, but I've noticed two differences when calling a Python program with them:

1. `atexit` is not triggered in case of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> with `subprocess` for the inner program.
2. `KeyboardInterrupt` is not raiised when using `subprocess` in the outer program.

I think this is related how signals are handled across/for the subprocess, but using `restore_signals=True` or `restore_signals=False` did not have an effect.

Is there a better way than calling `atexit._run_exitfuncs()` manually?

Test program:

```
import atexit
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time

if int(os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', 0)):
    atexit.register(lambda: print('atexit inner'))

    print('sub, press Ctrl-C')
    try:
        time.sleep(60)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # atexit._run_exitfuncs()
        print('kbd: inner')

else:
    atexit.register(lambda: print('atexit outer'))

    print('== with os.system')
    try:
        print(os.system('env RUN_MAIN=1 %s t-atexit.py' % sys.executable))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('kbd: outer1')

    print('== with subprocess.call')
    try:
        subprocess.call(
            ['env', 'RUN_MAIN=1', sys.executable, 't-atexit.py'],
        )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('kbd: outer2')

    print('== with subprocess.call (shell=True)')
    try:
        subprocess.call(
            'env RUN_MAIN=1 %s t-atexit.py' % sys.executable,
            shell=True,
        )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('kbd: outer3')

    print('exit outer')
```

Output:

```
== with os.system                      
sub, press Ctrl-C
^Ckbd: inner
atexit inner
0
== with subprocess.call
sub, press Ctrl-C
^Ckbd: inner
kbd: outer2
== with subprocess.call (shell=True)
sub, press Ctrl-C
^Ckbd: inner
kbd: outer3
exit outer
atexit outer
```

I've noticed this with Django's runserver, which uses a subprocess (and thread) when it uses the (default) feature to reload on changed files: in this case an `atexit` handler installed in the subprocess (via `pdbrc`) is not executed.

Comment: I'd love to answer but I can't... All I can say is that implementations of os.system and subprocess.call are completely different: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py vs https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.3/Modules/posixmodule.c.